# Hi guys, I am new to jupyter, I used Anaconda Prompt to run jupyter-notebook, but the notebook failed to connect to the kernel

Tags: anaconda, jupyter

[The screenshot of the error I got in the prompt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aQkyL.png)

(base) C:\Users\Ayman>cd desktop

(base) C:\Users\Ayman\Desktop>cd ml

(base) C:\Users\Ayman\Desktop\ML>conda activate ./my_env

(C:\Users\Ayman\Desktop\ML\my_env) C:\Users\Ayman\Desktop\ML>jupyter-notebook
[I 2021-11-24 09:56:06.789 LabApp] JupyterLab extension loaded from C:\Users\Ayman\Desktop\ML\my_env\lib\site-packages\jupyterlab
[I 2021-11-24 09:56:06.789 LabApp] JupyterLab application directory is C:\Users\Ayman\Desktop\ML\my_env\share\jupyter\lab
[I 09:56:06.805 NotebookApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: C:\Users\Ayman\Desktop\ML
[I 09:56:06.805 NotebookApp] Jupyter Notebook 6.4.6 is running at:
[I 09:56:06.805 NotebookApp] http://localhost:8888/?token=724d01899aa45347a06555cc200f7ebdf9c9e843c526ad7d
[I 09:56:06.805 NotebookApp]  or http://127.0.0.1:8888/?token=724d01899aa45347a06555cc200f7ebdf9c9e843c526ad7d
[I 09:56:06.805 NotebookApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).
[C 09:56:06.934 NotebookApp]

```
To access the notebook, open this file in a browser:
    file:///C:/Users/Ayman/AppData/Roaming/jupyter/runtime/nbserver-12888-open.html
Or copy and paste one of these URLs:
    http://localhost:8888/?token=724d01899aa45347a06555cc200f7ebdf9c9e843c526ad7d
 or http://127.0.0.1:8888/?token=724d01899aa45347a06555cc200f7ebdf9c9e843c526ad7d
```

[I 09:56:11.958 NotebookApp] Creating new notebook in
Bad address (bundled\zeromq\src\epoll.cpp:100)
[I 09:56:14.576 NotebookApp] Kernel started: 76e00e69-8ea6-47da-900c-b4c4146e8c34, name: python3

(C:\Users\Ayman\Desktop\ML\my_env) C:\Users\Ayman\Desktop\ML>Bad address (bundled\zeromq\src\epoll.cpp:100)
Bad address (bundled\zeromq\src\epoll.cpp:100)

Comment: I tried to downgrade tornado to 5.1.1., but that did not work out, I tried to install python and jupyter separately, but the error ramians.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way creating a conda environment using:

```
conda create -n my_env python=3
```

Activate the environment using:

```
source activate my_env
```

Install the ipykernel using:

```
conda install ipykernel

ipython kernel install --name my_env --user
```

Now open the jupyter and select the "my_env" from Kernel option. ( path : jupyter -> kernel -> change kernel -> my_env )

Comment: I followed your instructions, but the notebook failed to connect to the kernel

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: OSError: [WinError 10038] An operation was attempted on something that is not a socket
[IPKernelApp] WARNING | Parent appears to have exited, shutting down.

Comment: do you have the PHP latest version?

Comment: What is the relationship between PHP and jupyter?